# Type or namespace could not be found from App_code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a class called ArchivedFilesWrapper in the App_code folder of my project, however when I use this class in another file in a different folder i get error:

The type or namespace name 'ArchivedFilesWrapper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I thought every page should be able to find classes that are contained within the same project, but I guess this is not the case. Can someone please tell me what using statement I need to have?

Here is a snippet from my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EMCWebAdmin.App_Code
{
    public class ArchivedFilesWrapper
    {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it to a web app it should work. The downside is that it will no longer autobuild your code in app_code folder every time you change it and spin up the app. I have never seen a professional developer use a website project. I have no idea who MS were targeting when they created them.

Comment: Thanks to Ben's comment above

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem without converting it to web app? Like clear solution, etc?

Comment: @AnilSoman Not that I know of. Converting to a web app solved the problem for me

Comment: @johnmcp, you must have not got around much because the first thing most devs I've met do when they start a web project is to choose a web site, not a web app. Besides, the benefits of a website, IMO, outweigh that of the wep app, for the reasons you mentioned. Auto compile is bliss!

Answer (score 83):

Perhaps the problem will be solved by changing the **Build Action Property** of the *.cs source file to **Compile** from **Content**.  From the Solution Explorer right click on the source file and choose Property.

*Note that the **App_Code** folder is intended for use in **Web Site Projects**.*

Note that for a **Web Application Project** or **MVC** project, adding an **App_Code** folder to your project and putting *.cs files in it will cause problems. I ignorantly added an **App_Code** folder to my MVC project from the Solution Explorer. VS defaulted the name space to MyProjectName.App_Code. *In this case Visual Studio 2012 defaulted the Build Action to Content, even though the type was .cs code*. After I changed **Build Action Property** of the *.cs source file to **Compile** from **Content** the namespace was resolved in other folder locations of the project. However because of problems, I had to change the name of folder--see below.

**Important**

In the *MVC* or *Web Application* project, the **App_Code** folder is trouble because it has *Web Site* Project type semantics. This folder is compiled when published (deployed) to the server. By changing Build Action from Content to Compile, you resolve the namespace issue on your development environment by forcing immediate compilation, but you get trouble when the second compilation results in *`objects defined twice`* errors on deployment. Put the code files in a folder with a different name.  If you converted a Web Site to a Web Application, see the guidelines on the Net for this--not in the scope of this question.  To read more about **App_Code** folder in the different project types [see this blog](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)

Comment: Thanks many times.  I didn't even think to look at that.  I believe this happens when you drag and drop files into the project like I did.  It appears to mark all files regardless of extension as "Content".

Comment: By changing file's "Build Action" property from "content" to "compile", you are asking compiler to compile it prior to deploy. This is against the purpose of App_Code folder.

Comment: @liaqatali the difference between Web Site Projects and Web Application (MVC) Projects is the important point. The App_Code directory is not available from Solution Explorer as an ASP.NET folder type in Web Application Projects by design.

Comment: Yes, @subsci. There is a basic difference between WAP and WSP, but still you can add App_Code folder in WAP. The point I want to say is, you can add this folder, but you can't use it without changing its nature.

Comment: @liaqatali even if you 'change its nature', an App_Code folder has limited utility in WAP--as described in the Question. You are free to impose an App_Code folder on your project, but to do so goes against the design of ASP.NET, which in general is not a best programming practice. If you add another comment, would you be so kind as to share the compelling reason why **you** would **recommend** using an App_Code folder in a WAP.

Comment: No, I am not recommending it @subsci. My reservation is why App_Code folder exist in WAP? Does it make any sense, or is there any difference between App_Code and any other XYZ folder in Window Application Project?

Comment: I am working on a legacy Asp.Net webforms project, and I was pulling my hair why it is not recognizing the namespace. Thank you @subsci

Answer (score 5):

You need to add

```
using EMCWebAdmin.App_Code;
```

to all the pages you want to be able to use the class.

Alternatively you change the namesspace that the class is in to the same one that all the web pages use which presuming it is EMCWebAdmin

then in your class change

```
namespace EMCWebAdmin.App_Code
    {
...
```

to

```
namespace EMCWebAdmin
    {
...
```

This is a feature of visual studio, if you create a class in a folder structure, it uses a namespace that follows the folder structure.

Comment: That's actually what I thought I needed to do, but when I do that I now get the error "The type or namespace name 'App_Code' does not exist in the namespace 'EMCWebAdmin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Are you using a website project or a web application project.

Comment: If you convert it to a web app it should work.  The downside is that it will no longer autobuild your code in app_code folder every time you change it and spin up the app.  I have never seen a professional developer use a website project. I have no idea who MS were targeting when they created them.

Comment: That's got it thanks. I can live without the autobuild.
Still figuring out the quirks of Visual Studio, this one had me stumped. 
Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, put the calsses to another folder(not asp.net special folder), and only use the main namespace for the application is solve this issue.
Thanks johnmcp.