# Web.Api Attribute Not Showing on Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use Mike Wallace's "RequireHttps" attribute to force certain controllers to require SSL or not.

I have the code below, and  it builds fine.   But when I actually go to add the attribute to the controller, it fails.

I have other custom attributes that appear, and I have another that doesn't.   So it might be a project issue, though I tried a new project and it still failed.  The code is in the app_code folder.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;


namespace WebAPIService
{
    public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public RequireHttpsAttribute();

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.   Thanks.

EDIT:

*The error I get on the API Controller is:*
The type or namespace name 'RequireHttpsAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And the error it fails with is?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'RequireHttpsAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you included `WebAPIService` in the code file that is using the `RequireHttpsAttribute`?

Comment: yes, I have added. WebAPIService is actually the name of the project, so it shouldn't be necessary anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put your `RequireHttpsAttribute.cs` file in a different folder than `App_Code`, which is a special ASP.NET folder. Your namespace import should function correctly, then. If your project is a website project, converting it to a web app might also solve the problem.

If you want to learn more about the issue, I recommend you take a look at [Type or namespace could not be found from App_code folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178985/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-from-app-code-folder).

Comment: Thanks for the help.   I converted the project to a web app like the link suggested, and then had to re-create my file in another directory.