# Designer page is prepending Global to custom controls definition namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got a custom control defined in my App_Code folder.  When I add it to a page, I get the error `Type 'Global.XXX.xxx.MyControl' is not defined`

Class:

```
Namespace XXX.xxx
    Public Class MyControl
        Inherits TextBox
        ...code...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Page Useage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="xxx" Namespace="XXX.xxx" %>
...
<xxx:MyControl runat="server" id="StartTime" />
```

Designer:

```
Protected WithEvents StartTime As Global.XXX.xxx.MyControl
```

So what's happening is `Global` is being prepended to the namespace in the designer file.  For some reason, the IDE thinks my custom control is living in the global namespace, but as far as I can see from searching the Object Browser, it isn't.  Manually going in and deleting the prepended `Global` from the designer file allows me to build the page successfully, view it and test the functionality of my control, however this is far from an ideal solution, as the designer file is regenerated every time you make a change to the corresponding page.

Any ideas as to why it thinks my custom control, living in the App_Code folder, is in the Global namespace?  Any suggestions on a better fix than the manual one?

EDIT: Perhaps a better question would be how to get that namespace into the Global namespace, so that when it creates the designer file, it's correct?

Comment: You mention the designer : I take it that you have a usercontrol with a ascx file then? Just that this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx says you can't do that.

Comment: No, It's a VB file defining a CustomControl, in the App_Code folder.  It is not a usercontrol with an ascx file, though I've tried that route as well to no success (not putting in the App_Code folder, but just in a normal place in the project).

Comment: So you *still* get the Global added when the VB file is not in App_Code?

Comment: When it wasn't in App_Code previously I was unable to pull the control in at all.  The code I've been trying to get working is here, if you're curious.  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/12443/asp-net-outlook-like-time-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question [Type or namespace could not be found from App_code folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178985/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-from-app-code-folder) may be what you want.

Either put your class in a different folder or change the build settings as per http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Comment: I've already got my build settings to Compile, hence why it works correctly when I remove the `Global` from the generated code in the designer.  I've ported it to it's own class file (a couple different times, to no avail).  I don't recall the specifics of my other attempts, but I must have been trimming my Namespace out of them, because this time it's working just fine.  Thanks!