# Intellisense Works But I Get Type or Namespace Errors When Trying to Compile

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I am writing a .NET web application and I'm using a dataset to handle my data.

In the code, everything looks fine (no squiggly red underlines, in fact I can select the tableadapter I want to use).

However, when I try to run the program, I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ReleaseSet1TableAdapters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Why is the code working but the program isn't running? Attaching a picture of the code to show my green tableadapters where everything looks good.

I'm getting the same error for my gridviews, which are in the aspx file. Your help is appreciated; I'm at a loss.

Code excerpt

[image]

Here is the aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Sql;

public partial class Sched_Yesterday : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters.RollOutTableAdapter tblYesterday = new ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters.RollOutTableAdapter();
    ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters.RollOutTableAdapter tblYesterdaysDetail = new ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters.RollOutTableAdapter();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvYesterdaysReleases.DataSource = tblYesterday.GetDataByYesterdaySummary();
        gvYesterdaysReleases.DataBind();

        gvYesterdaysDetail.DataSource = tblYesterdaysDetail.GetDataByYesterday();
        gvYesterdaysDetail.DataBind();
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //required to avoid the run time error "
        //Control 'GridView1' of type 'Grid View' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."
    }
}
```

And the aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Sched_Yesterday.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sched_Yesterday" %>

<html>

<head runat="server">
    <!--Title-->
    <title>Yesterday's Releases</title>

    <!-- CSS -->  
    <link href="Content/CSS/skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/CSS/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/CSS/misc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Scripts -->          
    <script src="Content/JS/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Content/JS/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmRelYesterday" runat="server">

    <!-- Navigation/Header -->
        <div class="titleRectangle">
            Yesterday's Releases<br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperLinkIndex" runat="server" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Size="20px" 
            NavigateUrl="~/Index.aspx">Return to Main Menu</asp:HyperLink>            
        </div>  

    <!--Page Content -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="rectangle">
                <asp:Gridview 
                    ID="gvYesterdaysReleases" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CssClass="grid" 
                    HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    EmptyDataText="There were no releases deployed yesterday." 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False">                                
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:HyperLinkField 
                            DataNavigateUrlFields="Release" 
                            HeaderText="Release"
                            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Release_Detail.aspx?ReleaseName={0}" 
                            DataTextField="Release" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Scheduled" HeaderText="Scheduled" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <progress max= <%# Eval("Target") %> value= <%# Eval("Deployed") %>>                                                                   
                                    <div pseudo="-moz-progress-bar">
                                    </div>
                                </progress> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tgtPct" HeaderText="% Complete" />
                    </Columns>                    
                </asp:Gridview>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export Release Details" />
                <asp:Gridview 
                    ID="gvYesterdaysDetail" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CssClass="grid" 
                    HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    EmptyDataText="There were no releases deployed yesterday." 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True">                                                  
                </asp:Gridview>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question.  [Posting an image of the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) is considered rude here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Some additional explanation about [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5198140) (and there is a duplicate question linked there, covering screenshots of errors as well as code).

Comment: My apologies, I wanted to show where it was green and behaving correctly in the code. I am attaching the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the first two lines (after the public partial class line) to look more like this:

```
ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters tblYesterday = new ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters.RollOutTableAdapter();
```

Note the very first part has changed.. You're trying to instantiate a class using a method rather than the class name

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Taking out RolloutTableAdapter threw a new error:
Error CS0118 'ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters' is a namespace but is used like a type

Comment: Do you have a namespace and a type with the same name? That could explain it.

Comment: @akling can you paste the entire code into your question (edit it) so we can copy it and see what's happening?

Comment: @akling please post the code for the `ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters` class too

Comment: @Syntax Error: I do not have a class for that, I just have the ReleaseDataSet1.xsd file (and its accompanying files) which is the GUI where I added my tables and queries.

Comment: @akling Have you tried simply using `ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters tblYesterday = new ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters();`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, either. I did go to the ReleaseDataSet1.Designer.cs file and found 

namespace ReleaseSiteRewrite2018.App_Code.ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters

So I tried to qualify it as 

ReleaseSiteRewrite2018.App_Code.ReleaseDataSet1TableAdapters.RollOutTableAdapter

and it said "the type or namespace App_Code does not exist in the namespace ReleaseSiteRewrite2018 (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @akling Try `ReleaseSiteRewrite2018 tblYesterday = new ReleaseSiteRewrite2018()`, then use `tblYesterday.` to see what methods are available in intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link: [Type or namespace could not be found from App_code folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178985/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-from-app-code-folder) I changed my Build Action to Content and now everything is compiling correctly. I really appreciate everyone's help, especially @Syntax Error.